# TermsAndCOnditions Scroll with WebView and buttons

Tags: javascript, webview, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a ContentPage which has a WebView (html text) and buttons "I agree" and "Cancel"

Problem: I want a webView to insert into stack, therefore, I must declare Width and Height.
Height is my main problem, because I want to span or FillAndExpend WebView.

So I pursued for webView.Eval("some js code") function, but I cant get a return value (height of the html?)
Also, I approached from a different way, to get event when is webView onBottom, and then to get maybe some boolean value.

Here is the code:

```
StackLayout mainStackLayout = new StackLayout { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center };

        Frame f = new Frame { BackgroundColor = Constants.iBackgroundWhite };
        StackLayout motherStack = new StackLayout { Margin = new Thickness(15, 30) };

        StackLayout buttonStack = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Margin = new Thickness(0, 10)
        };
        Label captionLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = "Terms and Conditions",
            TextColor = Constants.iPink,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            FontSize = 25,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 15)
        };


        var body = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        body.Html = @"<html><body>
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam tritani interpretaris mel ei, perfecto 
 instructior ut vim. Usu ad erant maiorum, tollit latine ei ius, ea eos 
 vitae nominati iracundia. Consul laboramus eam ad, eu est nisl expetendis 
 philosophia. Doctus ceteros eu per, ut vel fierent similique accommodare, 
 ius similique consectetuer et.
 Te nec vero quas utamur, in possim nonumes inimicus his, an animal recusabo 
 per. Eos ut natum bonorum legimus. Nihil liberavisse no usu. Sea dignissim 
 mnesarchum cu, et per simul persius, constituto definitionem per in. No vix 
 novum verear apeirian, aliquam accumsan definitionem mel at. Mea et autem 
 phaedrum iracundia, reque vidisse at usu.
 Ad mea commodo oportere. Quo ad debitis accusata atomorum. His dicit 
 labores et, in dicat dolorum abhorreant est, ex qui voluptua oportere. Eum 
 ex nonumy cotidieque signiferumque. Laudem commodo omittantur quo in, voluptua 
 reformidans nam ad, ignota dicunt sed an. Mei ad sonet nonumes, no sit detracto 
 officiis.
 Cibo exerci duo eu. Has habeo atomorum disputationi te, ne has idque delicata. 
 Cibo nihil euismod qui ut. Dicit ubique maiorum duo et, eam ad probo percipit 
 sententiae. Quas lucilius vis ne. Id nec fabellas consetetur, sit id melius 
 impetus cotidieque, eum fierent praesent rationibus id. Qui et liber offendit 
 verterem, ad eripuit eruditi qui.
 Vis affert instructior cu, cum id principes adolescens. Per omnes nominati 
 salutatus at, ne audiam noluisse mel, aeque docendi fierent pro ne. At putant 
 voluptua vis, duo ne etiam tritani. Ut solet laudem qualisque usu, dicunt 
 adipisci his cu. Ea labore convenire corrumpit nec. Ne est quando virtute, 
 virtute adipiscing an ius, an mei iracundia posidonium

    </body> </html>";

        _webView = new WebView
        {
            Source = body,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            WidthRequest = App.ScreenWidth * 0.8,
            HeightRequest = 500
        };


        _webView.IsEnabled = false;


        #region Buttons
        Button okButton = new Button();
        okButton.SetWhiteButton();
        okButton.Text = "I ACCEPT";
        okButton.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) - 5;
        okButton.WidthRequest = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)) * 5;
        okButton.BorderRadius = Constants.BorderRadius + 5;

        Button cancelButton = new Button();
        cancelButton.SetDefaultButton();
        cancelButton.Text = "CANCEL";
        cancelButton.FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)) - 5;
        cancelButton.WidthRequest = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Button)) * 5;
        cancelButton.BorderRadius = Constants.BorderRadius + 5;

        bool isChekedTaC = false;
        okButton.Clicked += (s, e) =>
        {
            isChekedTaC = true;
            Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterOnePageNew(isChekedTaC, registrationRequestModel, "1234"));
        };

       #endregion

        //var a = _webView.Eval("window.onscroll = function(ev) { if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight){alert('youre on the bottom');}};"

        //_webView.Navigated += (o, s) => {
        //    _webView.Eval("alert('text')");
        //};
        buttonStack.Children.Add(cancelButton);
        buttonStack.Children.Add(okButton);
        buttonStack.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
        buttonStack.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        grid.Children.Add(_webView, 0, 0);
        //grid.Children.Add(buttonStack, 1, 0);


        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
        //sl.Children.Add(contentLabel);
        sl.Children.Add(_webView);
        sl.Children.Add(buttonStack);

        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(captionLabel);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(new ScrollView { Content = sl });
        //mainStackLayout.Children.Add(buttonStack);
        f.Content = mainStackLayout;
        motherStack.Children.Add(f);
        Content = sl;

    }



    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        Navigation.PopAsync();
        return true;
    }
```

I only want to present my two buttons, when HTML WebView reaches the bottom. How can I do that?

**#Option 1: return true/false when on bottom**
I managed half-way to get it right with XLabs HybridWebView. Here is the code, maybe for someone will be useful.

```
public class HybridView : ContentPage
{
    HybridWebView hybrid;
    public HybridView()
    {
        var stack = new StackLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White
        };

        var body = new HtmlWebViewSource();
        body.Html = @"<html><body>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, utinam tritani interpretaris mel ei, perfecto instructior ut vim. Usu ad erant maiorum, tollit latine ei ius, ea eos vitae nominati iracundia. Consul laboramus eam ad, eu est nisl expetendis philosophia. Doctus ceteros eu per, ut vel fierent similique accommodare, ius similique consectetuer et.
                        Te nec vero quas utamur, in possim nonumes inimicus his, an animal recusabo per. Eos ut natum bonorum legimus. Nihil liberavisse no usu. Sea dignissim mnesarchum cu, et per simul persius, constituto definitionem per in. No vix novum verear apeirian, aliquam accumsan definitionem mel at. Mea et autem phaedrum iracundia, reque vidisse at usu.
                        Ad mea commodo oportere. Quo ad debitis accusata atomorum. His dicit labores et, in dicat dolorum abhorreant est, ex qui voluptua oportere. Eum ex nonumy cotidieque signiferumque. Laudem commodo omittantur quo in, voluptua reformidans nam ad, ignota dicunt sed an. Mei ad sonet nonumes, no sit detracto officiis.
                        Cibo exerci duo eu. Has habeo atomorum disputationi te, ne has idque delicata. Cibo nihil euismod qui ut. Dicit ubique maiorum duo et, eam ad probo percipit sententiae. Quas lucilius vis ne. Id nec fabellas consetetur, sit id melius impetus cotidieque, eum fierent praesent rationibus id. Qui et liber offendit verterem, ad eripuit eruditi qui.
                        Vis affert instructior cu, cum id principes adolescens. Per omnes nominati salutatus at, ne audiam noluisse mel, aeque docendi fierent pro ne. At putant voluptua vis, duo ne etiam tritani. Ut solet laudem qualisque usu, dicunt adipisci his cu. Ea labore convenire corrumpit nec. Ne est quando virtute, virtute adipiscing an ius, an mei iracundia posidonium.
                      </body> </html>";


        hybrid = new HybridWebView
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            BackgroundColor = Color.White,
            WidthRequest = 300,
            HeightRequest = 600,
            Source = body

        };

        stack.Children.Add(hybrid);

        Content = stack;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        hybrid.InjectJavaScript("window.onscroll = function(ev) { if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight){alert('youre on the bottom');}};");
    }
}
```

Now I have to just figure it out how to get information to xamarin forms from js

Comment: You will have to use platform specific code.

Comment: Actually if you are using HybridWebView it should already have this option to call C# using RegisterAction.

Answer (score 1):

You can put "I Agree" and "Cancel" buttons into HTML and then inject to your old source. In this way, you can use single WebView to display all.

Comment: I exactly done this, but when I return action throgh C# Something like: `myvar.ReturnOnAction = (data => MyFunc()) //where MyFunc{App.Current.Main = new NavigationPage(new MyPage();}` when enteres in my method, program exits from application. Later on, I will post my full code. Tnx